# Is implicit casting considered to be a bad concept?

Tags: c++, c, types, casting

Why is implicit casting even allowed? I mean what is the benefit of casting a `float` to an `int` implicitly? Doesn't explicit casting makes a more readable and easier to debug code?

Comment: Yes, but it also breaks a lot of old code that uses implicit casting... It's part of the language, and has been since C was first created...

Comment: Well, in the case of float and int, I think it's not really that unreadable. It's visible, that the variable you assign the cast to is of type int, so there is no confusion here, even without the (int) explicit cast. And as far as I know, there are warnings in this case, so you surely won't miss it.

Comment: I wonder why someone will down vote on this question? its fair enough to ask this question.

Comment: @MatsPetersson There's certainly a lot of historical weight involved.  But even without it, I don't think you would ban _all_ implicit conversions.  Things like `T*` to `T const*`, for example.  (Even I'd accept that one.  And I'm very against implicit conversions in general.)

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski The problem typically isn't the type you're converting to (although it's not always that visible); it's the type you're converting from (which can be the result of an arbitrary expression).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: the large number of implicit conversions in C++ is due to
historical reasons, and nothing else.  I don't think any one considers
all of them a good idea.  On the other hand, there are many different
types of implicit conversions, and some of them are almost essential to
the language: you wouldn't like it if you needed an explicit conversion
to pass a `MyType x;` to a function taking a `MyType const&`; I'm pretty
sure that there is a consensus that const conversions adding const, like
this one, should be implicit.

With regards to conversions where there isn't a consensus:

- Almost no one seems to have a problem with non-lossy conversion;
  things like `int` to `long`, or `float` to `double`.  Most people also
  seem to accept conversions from integral types to floating point (eg
  `int` to `double`), although these can loose precision in some cases.
  (`int i = 123456789; float f = i;`, for example.)
- There was a proposal during the standardization of C++98 to deprecate
  narrowing conversions, like `float` to `int`.  (The author of the
  proposal was Stroustrup; if you don't like such conversions, you're in
  good company.)  It didn't pass; I don't know why exactly, but I suspect
  that it was a question of breaking too much from the traditions of C.
  In C++11, such conversions *are* forbidden in some newer constructs,
  like the new initialization sequences.  So it sounds to me like there is
  a consensus that these implicit conversions aren't really a good idea,
  but that they can't be removed for fear of breaking code or maybe just
  breaking with the tradition in C.  (I know that more than a few people
  don't like the fact that `someString += 3.14159;` is a legal statement,
  adding an ETX character to the end of the string.)
- The original proposal for `bool` proposed deprecating all of the
  conversions of numeric and pointer types to `bool`.  This was removed;
  it soon became apparent that the proposal wouldn't pass if it made
  things like `if ( somePointer )` (as opposed to
  `if ( somePointer != NULL )`) illegal.  There is still a large body of
  people (myself included) who consider such conversions "bad", and avoid
  them.

Finally: a compiler is free to issue a warning for anything it feels
like.  If the market insisted warnings for such conversions, compilers
would implement them (probably as an option).  I suspect that the
reason they don't is that the warnings have a bad reputation, due to
the initial implementations generating too many warnings.  Integral
promotion leads to a number of narrowing conversions that no one wants
to eliminate:

```
char ch = '0' + v % 10;
```

for example, involves an `int` to `char` conversion (which is
narrowing); in C++11:

```
char ch{ '0' + v % 10 };
```

is illegal (but both VC++ and g++ accept it, g++ with a warning).  I
suspect that to be usable, banning narrowing conversions would at least
have to make exceptions for cases where the wider type is itself due to
integral promotion, mixed type arithmetic and cases where the source
expression is a compile time constant which "fits" in the target type.

Comment: I like the C# requirement to make ref parameter passing explicit on the caller side, too. A function taking a `MyType const&` should not do any harm, but a function taking A `MyType &` may, unbeknownst to the caller.

Comment: You probably mean "Almost no one seems to have **a** problem..." (instead of "no problem") in your first bullet.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Re your first comment: I think that there are valid arguments for that, and at least some places have the rule in C++ to use `T*` instead of `T&`, so you have to take the address (which is a visible indication).  On the other hand, there are a lot of other issues you might want to address as well; one of the more frequent rules is to use a pointer if it will be saved (so you need to ensure sufficient lifetime).  I'm pretty open on this, and will go along with whatever the local coding guidelines suggest.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Re your second point: yes,  Fixed, and thanks.

Answer (score 7):

answer : Yes it is and here is an example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  unsigned int a=1;
  int b=-1;
  if(b>a)
     printf("-1 > 1 \n");
   else 
     printf("boring!\n");

return 0;
}
```

If you execute this code you will get

```
-1 > 1
```

This is due to the implicit cast of the variable `b` (`b` will be casted to `unsigned int` and turn `-1` to `4294976295` which is bigger than 1) which sometimes makes a problem so it will be a good habit to make explicit cast in order to make things clear for you and for programmers working on the same project !!

Comment: As a question of style: you shouldn't use unsigned types for numeric values to begin with.  And any time a conversion might change the value, it should be explicit.  But I think the question wasn't so much about what we should do when programming, but why the standard allows such silliness to begin with.

Comment: The careful programmer would enable extra warnings in the compiler ;-).

Answer (score 4):

Question:

> Why is implicit casting even allowed? I mean what is the benefit of
>   casting a float to an int implicitly?

The maintainer of the C FAQ, Steve Summit, says in a [tutorial](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4cb.html):

> The default conversion rules serve two purposes. One is purely selfish
>   on the compiler's part: it does not want to have to know how to
>   generate code to add, say, a floating-point number to an integer. The
>   compiler would much prefer if all operations operated on two values of
>   the same type: two integers, two floating-point numbers, etc. (Indeed,
>   few processors have an instruction for adding a floating-point number
>   to an integer; most have instructions for adding two integers, or two
>   floating-point numbers.) The other purpose for the default conversions
>   is the programmer's convenience: the mentality that ``the computer and
>   the compiler are stupid, we programmers must specify everything in
>   excruciating detail'' can be carried too far, and it's reasonable to
>   define the language such that certain conversions are performed
>   implicitly and automatically by the compiler, when it's unambiguous
>   and safe to do so.

Question 2:

> Doesn't explicit casting makes a more readable and easier to debug
>   code?

Answer:

> As mentioned above this is how implicit conversions happen but
>   explicit conversions "YES" adds readability.

Comment: Where does the standard say this?  I can't find it in my copy. (And the second sentence of your quote doesn't make sense.  Implicit conversions actually make additional work for the compiler.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Google pointed me to http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4cb.html (Steve Summit's C pages, "Intermediate C Programming Class Notes").

Comment: @PeterSchneider Which isn't a standard.  But it does surprise me some; Steve Summit usually knows what he's talking about, and the second sentence seems to be written by someone who has no idea how a compiler works.

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes i mis-wrote it as standard I see your answer talking about c++ since the question is dual tagged does that hold good for C also? and when you say implicit conversions are for some reasons , is the reason not as I mentioned? Or from where I took this detail ?

Comment: @Gopi I don't know the current thinking in the C committee, but a priori, I would suspect that backward compatibility remains a vital concern.  Historically, when C was being defined, that's just the way languages worked.  Fortran and PL-1 both have more implicit conversions than C. And C didn't have a `bool` type, so something had to work as if it were a `bool`.  A lot of software engineering knowledge that we just take for granted today---even things as "obvious" as indenting block structure---weren't established back then.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously breaking old code is what prevents new versions of the languages (C and C++) to change the rules. So the question is why this was permitted in the first place when C was conceived. The fundamental reason is, I understand, that C was modeled to be close to the hardware, and hardware doesn't (often, fundamentally) distinguish between addresses, integers and boolean types. Thus code like `int i=10; while(i--) doSomething(i);` or `int *p, offset; ... if(p) doSomethingElse(p+offset);` is almost directly translatable to machine code. In fact, it is not far from a macro assembler, most differences being the niceties around function calls. In my opinion it is also extremely readable. Any additional casts or explicit comparisons would compromise the bare-bones visibility of the logic. But that, of course, is a matter of taste and programming socialization.

And then yes, experience not available in the 70s has shown that some of the implicit conversions are sources of errors. If K&R could conceive C again they would probably change a few (literally few) things. The world being as it is though we have to make do with compiler warnings.